# Are there any best practices to instantiate a bunch of classes?

Tags: php

I am making a little PHP software that in order to run needs to instantiate a bunch of classes, like this:

```
$database          = new Database; //handle some kind of CRUD
$someFunctions     = new SomeFunction($database); //injecting the CRUD
$someMoreFunctions = new SomeMoreFunctions($database, someFunctions);
$evenMoreFunctions = new EvenMoreFunctions($database);
$app               = new AppManager($someFunctions, someMoreFunctions, evenMoreFunctions);
.............

$app->oneFunction()->doSomething->doSomeMore(); //working with the app
```

I eventually will have to put all the instantiation of the classes in a separate file or class to include or instantiate. The objective is to make all the instantiation transparent to the developer using the app.

I think the best way would be that the user just has to do something like this:

```
$app = App::oneFunction($maybeARecordId);
$app->doSomething();
$app->doSomeMore();
$app->maybeASaveFunction();
```

Are there any best practices on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The term you're looking for is called a "Dependency Injection Container" or a DIC. It will use the set bindings in order to create the instances for you.

Comment: Thank you. That concept is new to me, I will have to read about it.